# $(this).attr("name"); is working only for first element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_rhino_sub').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("name");
        alert("" + id);
        switch (id) {
            case '1':
                window.location = "mrhino.php";
                break;
            case '2':
                window.location = "mrhino.php";
                break;
            case '3':
                window.location = "mrhino.php";
                break;
            case '4':
                window.location = "mrhino.php";
                break;
            }
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" id="logo"><?php echo  " Welcome  " . $name ; ?></a>
        <div id="middle">Major Process</div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li>Click here for 
                    <a href="logout.php" class="a">logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM major_process WHERE parent_process ='0'; ";
            $query_result = mysql_query($query,$link);
            $row_count = mysql_num_rows($query_result);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
                ?>
                    <input style="height:75px; width: 225px;"
                        type="button"
                        class="btn btn-success round"
                        name="<?php echo''.$row[0]; ?>"
                        id="btn_rhino_sub"
                        value="<?php echo''.$row[1]; ?>">
                <?php   
            }    
        ?>
    </section>
    ...
</body>
```

Friends in this coding , I have fetched process_id and process name from database and displayed in button with process id as name of the button and process name as the value of the button . On click option I would like to get the name (i.e Process id fetched from DB) of the button clicked. so in jQuery I have a `onclick` event but `onclick` of first button alone the "Id" is alerted and page is redirected, while clicking on other buttons doesn't alert any values or redirected , but the values are fetched from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating duplicate IDs, **Identifiers in HTML must be unique** and this is the expected behavior.

Use class, Here In example below I have converted `btn_rhino_sub` in to a CSS class so that we can use [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
<input class="btn btn-success round btn_rhino_sub"  name="<?php echo''.$row[0]; ?>"value="<?php echo''.$row[1]; ?>" >
```

*Script*

```
$('.btn_rhino_sub').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("name");
});
```

However if you want to store costom value then use `data-*` prefixed custome tag, which can be fetched using `.data()`

Answer (score 0):

Ids should be unique to only one button on the page.   If there is more than one button that needs to be clicked, you will need to access the element by class.

```
<button class="btn_rhino_sub" name="whateverName">
```

You will need to change your click event to something like this:

```
$('.btn_rhino_sub').click(function()
{
  var id = $(this).attr("name");
  //rest of your code
```